# How to automatically set iTerm2 tab title to the filename opened in vim?

Tags: vim, tabs, iterm

I can get the vim title to display on my window by doing this:

```
let &titlestring = expand("%:t") . " @ " . hostname()
if &term == "screen"
  set t_ts=^[k
  set t_fs=^[\
endif
if &term == "screen" || &term == "xterm"
  set title
endif
```

But the tabs will say "Default".

From the commandline I can do this:

`echo -ne "\e]1;hello world\a"`

And that'll show "Hello World" in my tabs.

Is there a way to have vim write this stuff to my tab instead of title instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have iTerm, so I can't test this, but try adding this to [your `.vimrc`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34005877/90848):

```
set t_ts=^[]1;
set t_fs=^G
```

Type `CTRL-V Escape` for `^[` and `CTRL-V CTRL-G` for `^G`.

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't doing it for me.  I have the nightly build of iTerm and vim 7.4.488.  Setting these in my vimrc doesn't have an effect on the tab title.  Using the echo -e command in the iTerm2 FAQs does work for me: http://iterm2.com/faq.html

Comment: Same result on latest stable iTerm2.

Comment: @thoughtadvances This is in addition to setting the title and titlestring: `set title titlestring=[%F]`

Answer (score 12):

This works for me:

```
" Set the title of the Terminal to the currently open file
function! SetTerminalTitle()
    let titleString = expand('%:t')
    if len(titleString) > 0
        let &titlestring = expand('%:t')
        " this is the format iTerm2 expects when setting the window title
        let args = "\033];".&titlestring."\007"
        let cmd = 'silent !echo -e "'.args.'"'
        execute cmd
        redraw!
    endif
endfunction

autocmd BufEnter * call SetTerminalTitle()
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/bignimbus/1da46a18416da4119778

Comment: man, I have looked for this for quite a bit, it works perfectly here. Also combined with this to avoid full path on the other tabs https://superuser.com/questions/60555/show-only-current-directory-name-not-full-path-on-bash-prompt

Comment: Yes, this is the stuff!

Comment: This is definitely the right answer. For later viewers you shall paste this into `.vimrc` directly.

Comment: This works, but adds ~1,200 ms to my vim start up time.

Answer (score 1):

Just to piggy back on user2486953's comment above.

I was able to accomplish this with two super simple lines in my `~/.vimrc`:

```
set title
set titlestring=%f
```

(Lower case 'f' gives me just the filename, whereas capital gives the full path too)

i.e. I didn't have to set anything with escape sequences like the accepted answer above.  I am running *gnome-terminal* but I don't understand why iTerm2 would be any different for a VI setting.