# How to set terminal tabs titles in zsh, to vim filenames

Tags: macos, vim, terminal, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I am using a oh-my-zsh shell in an Apple terminal (2.11) in full screen, and by default the name of the tabs is the name of the program being run (eg. vim).

Is there an easy way to set the title of the individual terminal tabs to the filename currently opened with vim?

The terminal *window* title is already set, but not visible in full screen mode. What I'm looking for is to get at a glance the title of all terminal *tabs* where vim is opened.

Screenshot below:
[image: 5 macOS terminal tabs with vim open in each]

Comment: zsh is a shell, not a terminal. See [the difference](https://askubuntu.com/a/507138/356625). What terminal is this? Can you check the "help > about" at the top of the terminal window?

Comment: Looks like you're using a macOS terminal, so [here it is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49389564/9157799).

Comment: @MImamPratama this works for the terminal window title, not for individual tabs titles.

Comment: Looks like there is an answer on the [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/370287) sister site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution seems to use vim script shared in https://stackoverflow.com/a/48975505/4756084. It sets the title dynamically based on what file is currently being viewed — which you cannot obtain by going into Terminal Preferences > Tab, and checking "Active process name" and "Arguments" (that would only display the name of the file opened when typing `vim file.ext`, ignoring any file opened with `:e file2.txt`, switches between vim panes, etc.)

(With oh-my-zsh, uncommenting `DISABLE_AUTO_TITLE="true"` in `~/.zshrc` might help, as suggested in https://superuser.com/questions/292652/change-iterm2-window-and-tab-titles-in-zsh, although it seems optional after the step above.)